# Why can't I set the asp:Label Text property by calling a method in the aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can somebody please explain this to me:

I have a label and I want to be able to set the Text property by calling a method in the aspx file. It works fine if I set the property in code behind, but I really want to set this property in the aspx file.

I have tried a couple of things, but what I expected to work was this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=<%# GetMyText("LabelText") %> />
```

I get no errors when doing this, but my method is never called and the Text property is left empty.

Is it not possible to set property values to server side controls directly in the aspx without using resources or use hard coded values?

**Update:** My first try was:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %> />
```

But that results in the following error:

> Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax =<%# ... %> is *Data binding syntax* used to bind values to control properties when the DataBind method  is called.

You need to call DataBind - either Page.DataBind to bind all the controls on your page, or Label1.DataBind() to bind just the label.  E.g. add the following to your Page_Load event handler:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.DataBind();
        // ... or Label1.DataBind() if you only want to databind the label
    }
```

Using Text='<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>' as others have proposed won't work as you'll find out.  This syntax is inherited from classic ASP.  It can be used in some circumstances in ASP.NET for inserting dynamic values in static HTML, but can not be used for setting propeties of server controls.

Answer (score 3):

The sysntax you are looking for is `<%= %>` the `#` is for data binding. So your code should read:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>' />
```

**EDIT: This answere is incrrect**

I am leaving this answer here because lots of people agreed with me that this is infact the correct answer, but it will not work. This line of code will produce the following HTML output:

```
<span id="Label1"><%= GetMyText("LabelText") %></span>
```

Comment: I totally called it. Pretty good for having no clue about ASP and just pulling up a sample file to check.

Comment: That was also my first thought. But if I use the "<%=" syntax I get the following error: 

Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: +1.  Beat me to it, but the outer quotes will need to be single quotes. as in  Text='<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>'

Comment: Are you using double quotes or single quotes? or any at all? Try all three, as they have all more or less been suggested.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect this. Thanx David

Comment: The result of using single quotes is that the text <%= GetMyText("LabelText") %> is set as property value. If I use double quotes I get the same error message (Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.)

Comment: -1: -1: that won't work - Try it!  <%=.. %> is not used for server control properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>' />
```

**Edit**

Yep.  I was wrong.  @Joe was right.

---

However, THIS works (and I'm not sure what the difference is):

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%= GetMyText("LabelText") %></asp:Label>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected string GetMyText(string input)
{
   return "Hello " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input);
}
```

Comment: -1: that won't work - Try it!  <%=.. %> is not used for server control properties.

Comment: That's funny.  I use it all the time.  Unless the question is worded improperly, this isn't a databinding situation.

Comment: @David, I've copied your sample above in to an aspx file, and the resulting HTML was "<span id="Label1"><%= GetMyText("LabelText") %></span>" - i.e. the literal string "<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>" was used as the text property.  If you use it all the time, you must be doing something subtly different and I'd be interested to see what.

Comment: OK.  I have a feeling I'm going to be really embarassed when I get in to work to check my code.  Thanks, Joe.  I'll come back here and humbly apologize if my code differs.  I'll also post the code I actually use if it differs.  I bet it does.  At any rate, your answer worked for him, so I'm viting it up.

Comment: "I'm not sure what the difference is" - you can put HTML between the start and end tags of the Label control - in which case it will be rendered *instead* of the Text property.  And this HTML can contain the classic ASP "<% =Value %>" or "<% Response.Write(Value) %>".  In this case the code is executed during the Render phase.