# Why <%= %> works in one situation but not in another

Tags: asp.net

This is stemming from a bad answer I gave last night.  The curiosity as to why one method works and not the other is bugging me and I'm hoping someone smarter than me can give me the proper explanation (or point me to the documentation) of why the following behavior is as it is.

Given the following code-behind:

```
protected string GetMyText(string input)
{
  return "Hello " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input);
}
```

**Why does this work**

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%= GetMyText("LabelText") %></asp:Label>
```

**but this does not**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>' />
```

**Edit - added**

At the risk of having my original dumb answer downvoted more times, here's the link to the original question, since some of the answers I'm getting now were already covered in that question.

[Why can't I set the asp:Label Text property by calling a method in the aspx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529944/why-cant-i-set-the-asplabel-text-property-by-calling-a-method-in-the-aspx-file/1529970#1529970)

Comment: Does it have anything with single vs. double quotes? I know some languages make everything inside single quotes pure output, while text inside double quotes is evaluated first...

Comment: @peirix - Single vs. double quotes don't make any difference to ASP.NET syntax. The syntax follows XML syntax rules which state that you can use double & single quotes interchangeably, as long as you always end with the same thing you started with.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using `<%= %>` is equal to putting `Response.Write("")` in your page. When doing this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><%= GetMyText("LabelText") %></asp:Label>
```

The ASP.NET processor evaluates the control, then when rendering, it outputs the control's contents & calls `Response.Write` where it sees `<%=`.

In this example:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>' />
```

You can't use `Response.Write("")` on a Text attribute because it does not return a string. It writes its output to the response buffer and returns void.

If you want to use the server tag syntax in ASP.NET markup you need to use `<%# %>`. This combination of markup data binds the value in the tags. To make this work, you'll then need to call `DataBind()` in your page's `Load()` method for it to work.

Comment: +1 Yes, using response.Write inside a text property doesn't make any sense.

Comment: To expand on the `<%# %>` statement... It will be filled in upon data binding. This means that nothing will happen unless `DataBind()` is called on the control or its container. It's possible to call `Page.DataBind()` in the `OnLoad` event (like Dan said) if nothing else causes data binding on the control, but that's not necessary if the control is already databound.

Comment: This is the first time I have seen the <%= %> construct, and the explanation of it.  Does anyone know of a good source to explain in details all of the <%...%> constructs, what they do, and when to use them?

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  Well explained, and complete.  Thank you.

Comment: Here's an explanation of the various server tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Answer (score 5):

Because they are both server side instructions - the second piece of code is equivalent to:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='Response.Write(GetMyText("LabelText"))' />
```

Answer (score 5):

<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %> basically means

Response.Write(GetMyText("LabelText"));

Here it is OK.
     <%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>

However when you use this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>' />
```

It basically means:

Label1.Text = Response.Write(GetMyText("LabelText"));

which is a wrong statement.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong format:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%= GetMyText("LabelText") %>' />
```

Right format with using resources:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:Resource, MyText %' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this on server controls, if you have your LabelText in a Global Resource file:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: resourceName, LabelText %>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For it to work in the second case, you'd want it as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# GetMyText("LabelText") %>" />
```

And then Label1 will need to be databound.