# ASP.NET - Passing a C# variable to HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to pass variables declared in C# to html.  The variables have all been declared as public in the code-behind.

This is the HTML code I am using:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxChildID" Text='<%= Child_ID %>' runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

The problem is that when the page loads, the text '<%= Child_ID %>' appears in the textbox instead of the value in the variable.

What is wrong please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of this is assuming that this is just a textbox somewhere on your page, rather than in a DataBound control.  If the textbox is part of an itemTemplate in a repeater, and Child_ID is something that differes by data row, then all of this is incorrect.

Do this instead:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxChildID"  runat="server" Enabled="false"><%= Child_ID %></asp:TextBox>
```

In short, you're making the same mistake I was making when I asked this question: [Why <%= %> works in one situation but not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531586/why-works-in-one-situation-but-not-in-another)

---

Alternatively, in code-behind, you can have this in your ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxChildID"  runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

and this in your Code-Behind:

```
TextBoxChildID.Text = Child_ID;
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  However, now nothing seems to appear in the textboxes :s

Comment: Sorry, I had it wrong myself. <%#  %> won't work in this context either. It should be right now.  if so, go vote up the answer on my question - that guy did a great job of explaining it and he deserves the points.  And look at the notes on that answer as well - there's a link to a bunch of similar expressions that are helpful.

Comment: It is giving me the error: code blocks are not supported in this context

Comment: What was the issue? How did yo solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The variable must be public first. And:

```
'<%# Child_ID %>'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it only has to be protected.

Comment: As a matter of good practice would be to pass the correct value and not a variable to HTML. As there is a direct inheritance protected variable also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function abc()
    {
        var id = document.getElementById('txtTextBox');
        id.value=<%=MyProperty %>;
        alert(id.value);
    }
</script>
```

---

```
protected int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
 "<script language = 'javascript'>abc();</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

In The Codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HiddenField1.Value = Child_ID;
}
```

It would be the best way, it creates a hidden input with the value.