# Write date in asp:TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Value="<%= DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>" />
```

`Value="<%= DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>"` does not write date in txt field but whole string. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using JavaScript and jQuery:

```
var now = new Date();
$('#txtDate').text(now.getDate() + '/' + now.getMonth()+ '/' + now.getYear());
```

or plain JavaScript:

```
var now = new Date();
document.getElementById('txtDate').value = now.getDate() + '/' + now.getMonth()+ '/' + now.getYear();
```

or in markup (using `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.Text` property, it has no `Value` property):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text="<%# DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() %>" />
```

and after that call `this.DataBind();` or not for page, but your TextBox's parent control.

Comment: Your last method will actually render the `<% ... %>` within the TextBox. To set it using the spaghetti method, you're limited to standard, non-server input controls.

Comment: @Anthony: Yea, you're right. I got a mistake: need to use `<%#` instead of `<%=`

Answer (score 1):

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529944/why-cant-i-set-the-asplabel-text-property-by-calling-a-method-in-the-aspx-file/1530006#1530006).

As you've seen, you can't use the `<%= %>` construct to set a property of a server control.

The usual way to set a property in markup is to use a `<%# data-binding expression %>`