# Show Column Base on Condition

Tags: asp.net, .net, datalist

This below should be simple, but I am new so I don't know how to do this condition on the fly with ASP.NET.

Basically, I want to show the checkboxes if `Eval("CompanyID")` is NULL or nothing.

```
<asp:DataList BackColor="#ffffff" id="DataList1" DataSourceID="dsCompanyListPartialMatch">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <td style="width: 50px; border-right:1px solid black; border-spacing:0;"><%#Eval("Row")%></td>
        <td style="width: 70%"><asp:Literal ID="litFoo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Company")%>' /> </td>
        <td style="width: 10%"><asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CompanyID")%>' /> </td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <asp:CheckBox  id="check1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <%-- Example: If (Eval("CompanyID") == "" Then Show this Below. Else, don't show it --%>
            <td style="text-align:right;"><asp:CheckBox  id="check1" runat="server" /></td>
        <%-- END IF --%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS to hide the column.

```
<td style="text-align: right; <%# (Eval("CompanyID") == null || Eval("CompanyID").ToString() == "") ? "": "display: none" %>">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
</td>
```

Hide only CheckBox

```
<td style="text-align: right;">
    <div style="<%# (Eval("CompanyID") == null || Eval("CompanyID").ToString() == "") ? "": "display: none" %>">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Will `Eval().ToString()` throw exception when CompanyID is null?

Comment: This actually hide the checkbox, but also hide the <TD> tag, so the column as shifted.  Any suggestion just hide the checkbox only?

Comment: Try to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead.

Comment: @abatishchev We cannot use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() for object.

Comment: @milacay I updated the code. You'll need to user wrapper div.

Comment: You can can cast `String.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval())` thought

Comment: @abatishchev (string)Eval() will throw exception if null

Comment: No, cast doesn't throw exception if null.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
<asp:CheckBox Visible='<%= Eval("CompanyID") != null ' />
```

?

Comment: I am getting this error, when I tried your code: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: @milacay: are you sure you `<%=` and no any other? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529944/why-cant-i-set-the-asplabel-text-property-by-calling-a-method-in-the-aspx-file

Comment: yes, I put exact your suggested code and getting this error: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= Eval("CompanyID") != null ' for the 'Visible' property.

Comment: Your suggestion also work, but like this : 'Visible='<%# Eval("CompanyID").ToString() == "" %>''. Thank you for that also.